# Добавить текст в каждую строку файла

Tags: python, строки, файлы

Как средствами python дописать слово (в конкретном случае html тег) в начало и конец каждой строки файла?

Структура файла - ссылки на изображения:

```
"https://bla.bla/....jpg"
"https://bla.bla/....jpg"
"https://bla.bla/....jpg"
```

На выходе хотим получить:

```
<img src="https://bla.bla/....jpg">
<img src="https://bla.bla/....jpg">
<img src="https://bla.bla/....jpg">
```

Comment: bash подойдёт, м?

Comment: К сожалению нет.

Comment: @shkruiabla, в любом случае, вам уже дали 3 ответа, которые решают вашу задачу!

Comment: поставьте галочку под ответом, который вам помог. Если не трудно, конечно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действия:

- Считываете из текущего файла текст
- Разбиваете его на строки
- Записываете измененные строки в файл

Код:

```
file_name = 'urls.txt'

with open(file_name) as f:
    text = f.read()

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    for line in text.splitlines():
        f.write('<img src={}>\n'.format(line))
```

---

Если два файла – из которого считывают и в который записывают, то можно оптимизировать код, избавившийся от сохранения в памяти текста из файла.

В этом случае из файла `in_file_name` по одной строке будут высчитываться данные, изменяться и сразу же записываться во второй файл.

Код:

```
in_file_name = 'urls.txt'
out_file_name = 'img_urls.txt'

with open(in_file_name) as f_in:
    with open(out_file_name, 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            line = line.rstrip()
            f_out.write('<img src={}>\n'.format(line))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(r'C:\workspace\test.txt', 'r+') as f:
   lines = list(map(lambda x: '<img src={}>\n'.format(x.strip()), f.readlines()))
   f.seek(0)
   [f.write(l) for l in lines]
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

file = file.split('\n')
for i in range(len(file)):
    file[i] = '<img src={}>'.format(file[i])

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in file:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```